# Script manager is unable to open aspx page in new window in c#

Tags: c#

below is my Code

```
protected void btnprnt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Response.Redirect("Print.aspx");

    string url = "Print.aspx?ID=1&cat=test";
    string script = "window.open('" + url + "','')";
    if (!ClientScript.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered("NewWindow"))
    {
        //clientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "NewWindow", script, true);
        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this,this.GetType(), "NewWindow", script, true);
    }

   }
```

Problem is my Print.aspx is not open in new window.
the page is open but not in new window.
even page is redirecting.

Answer (score 1):

You need the following

```
string script = "window.open('" + url + "','_blank')";
```

Answer (score 0):

Your parameters for the `window.open` function are incorrect. The second parameter is overriding the target attribute, you should remove this.

```
string script = "window.open('" + url + "')";
```